# How can I count the selected files in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying to use the QFileDialog widget in PyQT5 in order to get the name of multiple files. I'm using the method **QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()** and, this method return the paths . how can i counts the files or paths like  **number of files is selected**

Comment: [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len).

Comment: In PyQt5, `getOpenFileNames` returns a tuple containing a `list` (the selected files) and a `str` (the selected filter). So after  `result = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()`, you need to do `len(result[0])` to get the count of files (which could be zero, if the user cancelled the dialog).